# use access form to edit data from a query result

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm brand new to Access 2010, well to Access in general. I have a query that returns 10 columns (the query is called pending_review, the source is a table called escalations) in the results, some of those fields are blank since they have to be reviewed. One of the resulting columns is the primary key.

So this is my problem: I need a to create a form where I can type the primary key and the fields on the form will populate with the info from that row so I can fill the blank spaces with information that I now have and then update the table.Once the table is updated, that row should no longer show on the query results.

What I have done is that I created the form, but I don't know how to do the part of typing the primary key and everything gets populated. A solution would be to make a combo box that shows me the primary keys of the rows in the query results, so that every time i edit something in one of those fields for the query to be run again and reduce the number of options in the combo box.

Question is, how do i do that? or is there an easier and better way to do it?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just create a new form using the `pending_review` query as a data source? Access makes it very easy--you can just use the form wizard. This gives you a form in which you can edit one row at a time. Presumably the `pending_review` query has a filter condition that checks for certain fields being blank (`null`) or not. If you finish editing a result row in the form, and refresh the form, the row should then disappear from the form because it will no longer be returned by the `pending_review` source query.

Even if you need to do something more complex, this should at least be a good start.